# Slow boot in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

Desktop comes very slowly after I push power button.how to solve it?

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.374s (kernel) + 6.377s (userspace) = 13.751s
graphical.target reached after 5.575s in userspace
ahmet@ahmet:~$ systemd-analyze blame
          2.181s dev-sda2.device
          1.642s tor@default.service
          1.432s systemd-journal-flush.service
          1.401s snapd.service
          1.172s ModemManager.service
          1.120s dev-loop0.device
          1.094s dev-loop1.device
          1.079s dev-loop2.device
          1.048s udisks2.service
          1.047s dev-loop3.device
           936ms accounts-daemon.service
           857ms grub-common.service
           773ms mpd.service
           739ms avahi-daemon.service
           700ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           682ms bluetooth.service
           653ms thermald.service
           649ms NetworkManager.service
           444ms systemd-udevd.service
           401ms wpa_supplicant.service
           346ms systemd-logind.service
           307ms rsyslog.service
           267ms systemd-resolved.service
           262ms gpu-manager.service
           257ms colord.service
           227ms upower.service
           210ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B044\x2d884E.service
           192ms apparmor.service
           189ms polkit.service
           175ms phpsessionclean.service
           174ms apport.service
           169ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           167ms swapdosya.swap
           167ms swapfile.swap
           146ms keyboard-setup.service
           127ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           120ms snap-ktube\x2dmedia\x2ddownloader-4.mount                                                                                                                                      
           117ms snap-gydl-2.mount                                                                                                                                                              
           107ms systemd-sysctl.service
           105ms systemd-journald.service
            98ms systemd-rfkill.service
lines 1-41
```

Comment: it doesn't seems to be slow.

Comment: but its on ssd.there are youtube videos which shows only 5 seconds are enough for everything.

Comment: Kubuntu, per se, may be a bit slow to start compared to some other systems. Do the other systems with 5s also have all the services you have? If, after it loads, Kubuntu works fine for you would the "slow" start-up still be a serious issue?

Comment: This is what i got from a ssd on Ubuntu: https://pastebin.com/WAk8ktSU